# Difference between "Azure Defender for MySQL" and "Advanced Threat Protection for Azure Database for MySQL"

Tags: mysql, database, azure

Is there any difference between "Azure Defender for MySQL" and "Advanced Threat Protection for Azure Database for MySQL"? or both are same?

If both are different, how to configure or set up Azure Defender for MySQL using Azure portal?

Thanks
Ravindra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/azure-defender-for-sql). It says Azure Defender provides a set of advanced SQL security capabilities, including SQL Vulnerability Assessment and Advanced Threat Protection. In other words, Advanced Threat Protection is one part of Azure Defender. You also can reference this [document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/advanced-threat-protection-for-azure-database-for-mysql-in-preview/?cdn=disable) to read more details.

Comment: You probably  mean *Advanced Threat Protection is one part of Azure Defender*?

Comment: Yes, it is. I've corrected my answer.